# Compass works on real device, but not on Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sensors

**EDIT:** Android studio was slow to tell me that `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` was deprecated. For some reason it wasn't telling me until long after writing and running the code. The problem still remains, however. I just wanted to add this discovery in my question.

I have an ImageView that acts as a compass. Everything works fine on a real device, but on my emulator, the extended controls have no effect on the ImageView.

If I go to Google Maps while on the emulator, I can see the compass working. Why doesn't my app work the same if it works on a real device?

fields:

```
 /*
COMPASS STUFF
 */
private ImageView compass;
private float currentDegree = 0f;
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
```

onCreate:

```
compass = findViewById(R.id.compass);
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
```

onResume:

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}
```

onPause:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}
```

onSensorChanged:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {

    float degree = Math.round(sensorEvent.values[0]);

    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree,
            -degree,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    rotateAnimation.setDuration(210);
    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    compass.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    currentDegree = -degree;
}
```

I honestly don't know what else to post, because I've tested it on 2 phones (Galaxy s6 Active, and Galaxy s8 Edge Plus), and it worked on both. It just doesn't do anything in the emulator.

I'll show proof it works on my own physical device.

[image]

[image]

Fails on emulator.... --_______--

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions? I would really like to test other APIs/devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it turns out that my discovery regarding the deprecated `Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION` fixed my problem. I utilized the `Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` and `Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD` constants and my compass works in my emulator now. :-)

I used [this](https://www.wlsdevelop.com/index.php/en/blog?option=com_content&view=article&id=38) blog to help me understand the usage of the sensors.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOQxq2YpEjQ) is the step by step video version of the blog.